# Landscape Based Management of Public Cloud

Tags: cloud, landscape

We are en route to deploy Ubuntu OpenStack for Public Cloud.However following are the showstoppers:

QUESTION 1: We have been told that two separate admin consoles will be required.

1. Hardware via NAGIOS (custom built)
2. Everything else via Landscape (focusing on operations and ignoring Juju, MaaS)

A few quotes on Ubuntu site indicates that hardware can be monitored via landscape, is that so. Can you share more details or screenshots where this has been done before.

QUESTION 2: Is a KPI driven SLA possible. Specifically as in Azure where you can monitor the overall KPI and if something goes wrong, you can drill down till you reach the module/component/node causing the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can just try it out for yourself.

The easiest way is to sign up for a trial at https://landscape.canonical.com. It doesn't have the cloud installer option, but you can see all the rest and register machines to it.

If you want to deploy Landscape locally and install your own OpenStack cloud, follow the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

Answer (score 1):

1. Landscape does have monitoring capabilities built in, yes, however comparing it with NAGIOS it is lacking in many areas.  It's not currently intended to supplant any kind of monitoring solution you have in your Lab.
2. I don't know enough about Azure's KPI/drill-down features to answer intelligently, but it doesn't sound similar to what is currently in place for monitoring Openstack in Landscape.  I'd recommend you try out the LDS Beta, as @andreas suggested.  Also, [get in touch with Canonical directly](http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us) if you have deeper questions about comparing this solution, or are interested in it for your business.

Comment: Thanks andreas and dpb, I have already contacted Canonical for more details. As soon as I get them, will share them here for future reference. But in principle I agree with what was stated - Landscape is lacking, or evolving, compared to Nagios or Azure.